# Referencing a model's Show View form another model's Index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In the Color Index View, the following produces a clickable link that takes me to the Color Show View.

```
<% @colors.each do |color| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to color.color_name, color_path(color) %></td>
```

in the model, I have:

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
```

I also have a Product Index View, and I want to create a clickable link to the Color Show View, but I can't make it work.

This does not work (for one thing, color_name is not the primary key in the color table:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to product.color_name, product.color_name, color_path(color.color_name) %></td>
```

in the model, I have:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :colors
```

This is not working and I'm getting an error when I try the Color Index View, something like:

`undefined local variable or method color`

Any ideas?

## Solution:

Here's what ended up working:

```
<% color_id = Color.find_by_color_name(product.color_name) %>
<td><%= link_to product.color_name, color_path(color_id) %></td>
```

It could also obviously be done on a single line, but two lines makes the code more readable (I think)

What I don't understand is why someone found it necessary to downgrade the question.

Comment: You product has_many colors. Which color should it link to?

Comment: link_to product.color_name, color_name is in the colors table, but is not the primary index

Comment: Interesting. Another person did a "drive-by" downgrade of this question, without leaving a comment. That makes two. If admins are reading this, I believe it's only fair to allow a downgrade, only if the person can explain why they did it, and not just because they're drunk with power. I thought that the objective here is to research, ask and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`color.color_name` is giving you error because you don't have color object on Product Index View.

Try `<td><%= link_to product.color_name, product.color_name, color_path(product.color) %></td>` if there is one-to-one relationship

Try `<td><%= link_to product.color_name, product.color_name, color_path(product.colors.first) %></td>` if there is one-to-many relationship

Comment: Right, and this is why I'm asking the question here. How do I reference a model's object from another model's object

Comment: Depending on relationship between two models. If product has one color then product.color. And if product has many colors then product.colors. Product is an object of your Product model.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper Have a look at my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16957237/1376448). Maybe that can help you straight. :)

Comment: If you want that it should link to the same color as of product then do product.colors.find_by_color_name(product.color_name) instead of product.colors.first

Comment: While the syntax you provided did not work the find_by_color_name gave me the clue I needed to find a solution, so I will mark this as an answer. Please see my edited question for the answer.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper - Good. Somehow my ans helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Product` `has_many` `colors`. Therefore, your code should be something like this:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
  <% product.colors.each do |color| %>
    <td><%= link_to color.color_name, color_path(color) %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

It iterates on the colors of your each product and shows `link` to their `show` path.

Caution: Probably subjected to N+1 problem. Above is just supposed to give you direction.